# Parse DateTime in format: 15:31:58:13943730921

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I parse the following time in C# ?

```
15:31:58:13943730921
```

What are the last 11 digits?

Comment: You're asking us what the last 11 digits are? You should know that!

Comment: @Lloyd Less than ticks. A tick is 1/10,000,000 of a second, that ones are 1/100,000,000 of a second.

Comment: If they are fractional seconds, the `DateTime` struct will not have enough precision. It can hold 7 digits (one tick is 100 nanosecond).

Comment: Where you got this string from?

Comment: You can split it by ":" and then create it using DateTime ctor: new DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int milisecond)

Comment: @Oleksandr: How do you know that `13943730921` are the milliseconds? Btw, it's even too large for `int`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I wouldn't be asking if I knew. The string is from a log file.

Comment: It could be anything; doesn't even have to be part of the time stamp; for example, it could be a process ID. Which software is writing the log file?

Comment: @dtb it's definitely time.

Comment: Round it to 15:30. Who needs to be *more* precise anyway...

Comment: @Corak I do. Precise to milliseconds.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Noticed that. Miliseconds can be specified in the 0 to 999 range.

Comment: Okay, as others said, you can't get more precise than seven digits in .Net. So change the last `:` to `.`, get rid of `0921` and `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss.fffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. - If you need less precision, adjust the `f`'s and get rid of the appropriate amount of digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something naive would be:

```
var time = "15:31:58:13943730921";
var str = time.Split(':');

var res = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(str[0]), int.Parse(str[1]), int.Parse(str[2])).Add(TimeSpan.FromTicks((long.Parse(str[3]) + 5000) / 10000));
```

Note that it won't work if the number of digits of the fractions of seconds change.

Ah... and it's a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime` probably :-)

The `+ 5000) / 10000` is to round to the nearest `Tick`.

A more complete solution that will handle any number of digits:

```
var time = "15:31:58:13943730921";
var str = time.Split(':');

// Used for the rounding
int carryover = 0;

if (str[3].Length < 7)
{
    str[3] = str[3] + new string('0', 7 - str[3].Length);
}
else if (str[3].Length > 7)
{
    char eight = str[3][7];

    if (eight >= 5)
    {
        carryover = 1;
    }

    str[3] = str[3].Remove(7);
}

var res = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(str[0]), int.Parse(str[1]), int.Parse(str[2])).Add(TimeSpan.FromTicks(long.Parse(str[3]) + carryover));
```

Note that the `TimeSpan` constructor doesn't support a hour/minute/seconds + ticks, so we have to handle it in a different way (by using the `.Add`). Other solutions are clearly possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done.

```
    internal string GetTime(string line)
    {
        // ...

        string tmp = time.Substring(0, 12);

        time = DateTime.ParseExact(tmp, "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Ticks.ToString();

        return time;
    }
```

Comment: What about the remaining digits? are they meaningless?

Comment: I have no idea, figuring that out was the point of this so question.

Comment: better ignore that `fff`

Comment: Why not `"HH:mm:ss:fffffff"`? You would need to cut off later, of course, as in `string tmp = time.Remove(16);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round correctly to a whole number and ticks, with .NET 4.0 and later you can do:

```
string time = "15:31:58:13943730921";
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time.Remove(16), "h':'mm':'ss':'fffffff", null);
if (time[16] >= '5')
    ts += new TimeSpan(1L);  // add one tick for better rounding
Console.WriteLine(ts);
```

`16` is the index in the string of the first character that we have to throw away.

Comment: This won't work if the hour has a single digit (9:...), because it would need to be `time[15]`. The same if hour has 3 digits(123:...)

Comment: @xanatos Very good point. One could substitue the `16` with some index relative to the last colon, as in `int idx = time.LastIndexOf(':') + 8;`.

Answer (score -1):

May seem like an obvious answer.. But the question isn't too clear.

```
DataTime time = DateTime.Now;
string myTime = time.ToShortTimeString();
myTime = myTime.SubString(0, 7);
```

Comment: This throws with my current `CultureInfo`. The string is not even seven chars long, so the index is bad. Besides, how does this answer his question?